# Data modelling a user table with multiple addresses in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling, cassandra-2.0

I am just starting out in Cassandra. I am testing following data model. I was wondering how can this be modeled in Cassandra?

```
Users
{ 
    "userId" : "73180" , 
    "firstName" : "John" , 
    "lastName" : "Doe"
    "addresses" : 
    { 
        "type" : "homeAddress"
        "street" : "a pretty street" , 
        "city" : "Some city" , 
        "state" : "CT",
        "country" : "US"
        "zipcode" : 55555
    } , 
    { 
        "type" : "businessAddress"
        "street" : "an office street" , 
        "city" : "Some city" , 
        "state" : "CT",
        "country" : "US"
        "zipcode" : 55555
    } , 
}
```

Specifically, how can I model multiple addresses for each user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While modeling addresses as a user defined type (UDT) is a good approach, you should also consider what your query patterns will look like.  Will you be querying users only by `userid`?  Or will you want to query them by name?

To demonstrate this, I'll create an address UDT and design a `usersByLastName` query table:

```
CREATE TYPE address (
  street TEXT,
  city TEXT,
  state TEXT,
  postal TEXT,
  country TEXT);

CREATE TABLE usersByLastName (
  userid BIGINT,
  firstName TEXT,
  lastName TEXT,
  addresses MAP <TEXT, FROZEN <address>>,
  PRIMARY KEY (lastName,firstName,userid));
```

Note that `addresses` is created as a MAP of `address`, so that you have some flexibility in type (home, office, shipping, billing...etc) and number of addresses that you can add per user.

Next, I'll INSERT some data and query by `lastName`, which yields:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROM usersbylastname WHERE lastname='Doe';

 lastname | firstname | userid | addresses
----------+-----------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      Doe |      Jane |  73184 | {'business': {street: 'A Office St.', city: 'Somecity', state: 'CT', postal: '55555', country: 'US'}, 'home': {street: 'B Pretty St.', city: 'Somecity', state: 'CT', postal: '55555', country: 'US'}, 'shipping': {street: '1187 Huntervasser', city: 'Los Angeles', state: 'CA', postal: '90036', country: 'US'}}
      Doe |      John |  73180 | {'business': {street: 'A Office St.', city: 'Somecity', state: 'CT', postal: '55555', country: 'US'}, 'home': {street: 'A Pretty St.', city: 'Somecity', state: 'CT', postal: '55555', country: 'US'}}

(2 rows)
```

This is one way which you could model this.  Again, it is important to consider your query requirements.

Edit: I'm at the Cassandra Summit keynote right now, and Jonathan Ellis just demo'd a user table with a map of addresses, pretty much exactly how I did.

Comment: how about creating two `Map` data types : `Home_Address` and `Business_Address`, is it make any difference compare to UDT ..?

Comment: @sras The problem I see with that solution, is that it mixes your business logic with your data model.  Now any new address types required by a future business case will also require a schema change.  Using a MAP of addresses does a better job of future-proofing you from having to make those types of changes to your model.

Comment: Thank you for the response and the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably want to create a [user defined type](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql-in-2-1) for an address, and then use it for a home_address and business_address field.